How to setup Office365 online account?
I'm a bit clueless about how to login into "online account" for Office365 in Ubuntu Gnome.
When you want to login the account, you're supposed to provide Client ID and Tenant ID as you can see here.

I registered an app in Microsoft Entra website, to obtain client and tenant ID, but when I try to login from Gnome, it redirects me to web browser and I receive error saying AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application, as you can see here.

I guess I need to specify "redirect Uri", but I have no idea what kind. I didn't find any documentation for this. Does anyone know how to set it up?

client id is optional, try just entering tenant id which should open a permissions request in your browser

I tried that and I got error saying: Need admin approval. This app may be risky. If you trust this app, please ask your admin to grant you access.
I will try to get app whitelisted by my admin and see if that works. But in the meantime, is there a way to avoid requesting admin access, by creating an "app" on your own in MS Entra?
